# C# Asynchronous call without EndInvoke?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, action

Take the following classes as an example.

```
public class A
{
   // ...
   void Foo(S myStruct){...}
}

public class B
{
   public A test;
   // ...
   void Bar()
   {
      S myStruct = new S();
      test.Foo(myStruct);
   }
}
```

Now, I want the method-call test.Foo(myStruct) to be an asynchronous call ('fire-and-forget'). The bar-method needs to return as soon as possible. Documentation around delegates, BeginInvoke, EndInvoke, the ThreadPool etc. isn't helping me find a solution.

Is this a valid solution?

```
     // Is using the `EndInvoke` method as the callback delegate valid?
     foo.BeginInvoke(myStruct, foo.EndInvoke, null);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not required to call `EndInvoke`; not calling it merely means:

- You don't get the return value from the method.
- Any exceptions thrown during the method execution will simply disappear.

It sounds like you want to 'fire-and-forget', so the easiest way to do this is to use an anonymous delegate, for example:

```
var del = new Action(foo.Bar);
del.BeginInvoke(iar =>
{
   try
   {
      del.EndInvoke(iar);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // Log the message?
   }
}, null);
```

This is what happens when you execute this code:

1. A new thread is allocated (put simply) for the delegate.
2. The thread is given the delegate `del` and the anonymous delegate (`iar => ...`).
3. The thread executes `del`.
4. When it is finished executing (or an exception occurs) the result or exception is stored and the anonymous delegate is executed.
5. Inside the anonymous delegate, when `EndInvoke` is called the result from the method is either returned, or the exception is thrown (if one occurred).

Note that the above example is very different from:

```
// This is pointless and is still, essentially, synchronous.
del.EndInvoke(del.BeginInvoke(null, null));
```

**Edit:** You should always call `End*`. I've never found a scenario where not calling it presents a problem, however that is an implementation detail and is [relying on undocumented behavior.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585042/is-delegate-endinvoke-really-necessary)

Finally your solution would crash the process if an exception is thrown, <strike>you can simply pass null as the delegate if you don't care about the exception (`del.BeginInvoke(myStruct, null, null);`).</strike> So as a final example what you are looking for is probably:

```
public class A
{
    // ...
    void Foo(S myStruct){...}
    void FooAsync(S myStruct)
    {
        var del = new Action<S>(Foo);
        del.BeginInvoke(myStruct, SuppressException, del);
    }

    static void SuppressException(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            ((Action<S>)ar.AsyncState).EndInvoke(ar);
        }
        catch
        {
            // TODO: Log
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: True, you are not "required" to call `EndInvoke`, but if you don't you'll get memory leaks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712741/why-does-asynchronous-delegate-method-require-calling-endinvoke?rq=1

Comment: @MattKlein no it doesn't. https://gist.github.com/jcdickinson/9109599 . SLaks' answer is somewhat correct though, in certain scenarios some tracking is done with `Begin/End-Invoke` pairs - one example is: if you don't call `EndInvoke` on `Socket` operations your socket performance counters will go completely out of whack (no memory leak, the values will just be wildly incorrect).

Comment: Perhaps this would be a valuable comment to add to SLaks' answer.

Comment: It might helps others as per this thread it is the right approach to 'must call EndInvoke()'. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585042/is-delegate-endinvoke-really-necessary

Comment: can you pass null instead of a callback method if you don't need the return value?

I assume that would be the case

Answer (score 3):

I would say that your best option is to use the `ThreadPool`:

```
void bar()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o=>
    {
        S myStruct = new S();
        test.foo(myStruct);
    });
}
```

This will queue the snippet for execution in a separate thread. Now you also have to be careful about something else: if you have multiple threads accessing the same instance of `A` and that instance modifies a variable, then you must ensure that you do proper synchronization of the variable.

```
public class A
{
    private double sum;
    private volatile bool running;
    private readonly object sync;
    public A()
    {
        sum = 0.0;
        running = true;
        sync = new object();
    }

    public void foo(S myStruct)
    {
        // You need to synchronize the whole block because you can get a race
        // condition (i.e. running can be set to false after you've checked
        // the flag and then you would be adding the sum when you're not 
        // supposed to be).
        lock(sync)
        {
            if(running)
            {
                sum+=myStruct.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        // you don't need to synchronize here since the flag is volatile
        running = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Callback model explained @ [What is AsyncCallback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047662/what-is-asynccallback/1047677#1047677)

That way your EndInvoke will not be in bar(), but in a separate callback method.

In the example, the EndRead (corresponding to EndInvoke is in the callback method called CompleteRead rather than the calling method TestCallbackAPM corresponding to bar)

Answer (score 0):

This is an option:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(bcl =>
{
    var bcList = (List<BarcodeColumn>)bcl;
    IAsyncResult iftAR = this.dataGridView1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        int x = this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                string imgPath = bcList[i].GifPath;
                Image bmpImage = Image.FromFile(imgPath);
                this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[x].Value =bmpImage;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }); 
    while (!iftAR.IsCompleted) { /* wait this*/  }
}, barcodeList);
```